# Azure Blob Storage SAS Token dose not expire as expected

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-blob-storage

My application generates SAS tokens to access existing blobs within my container. However, my SAS token dose not look like it is expiring. I am able to view and get blob from container way past expiration time I am claiming.

Here is the code :

```
  public string GenerateSasToken([NotNull] string containerName, [NotNull] string blobName)
    {
        var startTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
        var expiredTime = startTime.AddSeconds(20);

        var blobClient = new BlobClient(_options.Value.ConnectionString, containerName, blobName);
        var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read, expiredTime)
        {
            BlobName = blobName,
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            StartsOn = startTime,
            ExpiresOn = expiredTime
        };
        var uri = blobClient.GenerateSasUri(sasBuilder);
        return uri.ToString();
    }
```

Token been generated is valid and I am able to use it, but it dose not expire after 20 seconds in fact it dose not expire even after 15 minutes.

Am I missing something within this API?

Thank you!

Edit:

I am attaching SAS token that was generated.

```
?sv=2020-08-04&st=2022-01-24T21%3A20%3A41Z&se=2022-01-24T21%3A21%3A01Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=signature-here
```

Comment: I suspect you should be using `DateTime.UtcNow`, not `DateTimeOffset.UtcNow`. That said: you should show your sas string in your question, to see what the actual start and end times are. One other thing: 20 seconds really isn't enough time for a sas token, especially when considering clock drift. You may want to rethink start and end time...

Comment: Thanks for the thought. This is for POC to check if SAS token is actually been expired. This is my main concern atm. 
I will edit question and add sas token I get.
Also, per documentation they API is using `DateTimeOffset`

Comment: Please don't share the actual uri to the blob object. Just show the sas, to verify that you have proper start and end time.

Comment: yes, that would be very bad :), thank you for your consern.

Comment: Please try the expired SAS URL in a different browser. I’ve seen it happening where browser is caching the data.

Comment: Omg, I spend whole day on this, you are right it is actually expiring it, just caching. Do you think I can override caching headers in the request for SAS token?

Comment: Yes, you can override the cache-control header in SAS token.

Comment: Could you be kind enough to sent me documentation on this, I am having difficulty finding anything on this API for dotnet core.

Comment: @DavidMakogon please ignore me, I am been a little silly, there is a cache control property on the `BlobSasBuilder`. Thank you sir!

Comment: @kkdeveloper7 - Please provide an answer based on the solution you came up with. It will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the SAS token is expired, because of the browser caching, you would still be able to access the blob storage using the same SAS token

In order to avoid this, you can override the cache-control header in the SAS token as suggested by @Gaurav Mantri

You need to set **CacheControl** value in your BlobSasBuilder function to override the cache-control header

Your BlobSasBuilder function can be as below:

```
var sasBuilder = new BlobSasBuilder(BlobContainerSasPermissions.Read, expiredTime)
        {
            BlobName = blobName,
            BlobContainerName = containerName,
            StartsOn = startTime,
            ExpiresOn = expiredTime,
            CacheControl = "max-age=" + expiredTime
        };
```

Comment: Yes, that was the solution. Overriding `CacheControl` property expires cache